# Strange privilege problems on Windows 7 with cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, windows-7, cygwin

I have written a series of shell scripts which purpose is not really the matter at hand, the problem is with permissions (?). These scripts run on both Linux hosts and Windows XP hosts without problems.

However, on Windows 7, something happens and I cannot fathom the reason why.

The first thing this script does is source a file (`source utils.conf`) which is in the same directory as the script itself. But when the script is invoked, the output is:

```
source: utils.conf: file not found
```

And the script barfs (by design). It does not even say "permission denied", but "file not found". And this is not a typo, it DOES say `file not found` and not `no such file or directory`.

But... If I am at the prompt and type:

```
(source utils.conf; echo $SOMEVARFROMTHATFILE)
```

it works OK!

What's more, I checked via the GUI that the user had the permissions to read and execute on all relevant files: this is the case.

Why doesn't the script work?

Comment: There is no indication in the above that this has anything to do with privileges. Why do you think that? What happens when you type `source nonexistentfile` at the prompt? On Bash 3 and 4, I get `bash: nonexistentfile: No such file or directory`. It is strange that you get `file not found` instead.

Comment: It _does_ say "file not found"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be related to this, which was a bug that was fixed in newer versions ( 4)

http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg05791.html

Comment: That's it! Even though the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, it was invoked with `sh thescript.sh`... But bash is version 4.1.x though. Thanks!